# motorola DROID xt926

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

My phone has a cracked calibration ( the fore glass) with a good screen but yet it freezes while loading and then restarts. i never get to even see the homescreen before it restarts over again. Nw, I'm confused because i'm not sure if its going to work properly once i change the screen/calibration or its just another hardware problem from the board. Can someone please enlighten me on this?.. i want to know if the cracked calibration is liable to make the phone hang while booting.
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The crack in the glass itself can't cause the kind of problem you're describing, but it's possible that it's not just the glass that's cracked, but the touchscreen sensor. This looks like a thin, transparent plastic film under the glass. If this is damaged, it could be causing a power short or sending bad signals to the rest of the phone hardware, causing it to fail during startup.

In short, from what you've described there's no way to know for sure whether replacing the touchscreen will fix the problem. An experienced phone technician might be able to examine the electrical signals and determine if the touchscreen is still working, but that's probably harder and more expensive than simply replacing it to see if it fixes it. That said, taking the phone apart to replace the screen might make it obvious by letting you see any physical damage to other internal components.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Dan, i feel a little more relief, knowing the problem still surrounds the screen as a whole and not other parts from the main board. I would gladly purchase the whole screen, but the only issue i'm having now is getting the phone accessories since it happens to be so scarce here in Nigeria. I cant even say i've seen any other person using this my exact model, except lots of xt912s and xt910s. And the idea of shipping it down scares me because it costs quite much. Whew!